# Variance of mix of normals

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, gaussian-mixture-distribution

Suppose we have $n$ random variables distributed normally with the same mean and different variances. Suppose we know these variances. Which will be the variance of the marginal distribution induced by a finite mixture of $n$ normal distributions with the same mean and different variances?

Comment: The variance of the sum the $n$ random variables?  Or the variance of the marginal distribution induced by a finite mixture of $n$ normal distributions with the same mean and different variances?

Comment: The second one. Sorry it should be easy, but can not figure out...

Comment: You may want to rephrase your question to clarify exactly what it is you're asking.

Comment: Please edit your question, don't just clarify in comments

Comment: But the question did not have a word or a sign of sum...I do not understand the need of clarifications, but thank you.

Comment: Based on your comments, it is by no means obvious that you understand where your descriptions are not being understood. The complete calculation for the variance of a random variable that has a normal _mixture_ density, that is, the density is of the form $$f(x) = \sum_{I=1}^n p_i f_i(x), \ \ \ p_i > 0,\ \ \  \sum_ip_i = 1,$$ is given in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/195934/15941) on math.SE. Please read it and decide if that is what you wanted to know. If not, perhaps you can clarify further what _you_ understand by "finite mixture of random variables"

Comment: The answer is exactly to the question I was asking, however, my "big" problem I am trying to solve has nothing to do with the question...I have time series, at each time point it can be modelled as a normal mixture with known means, each time series have an additional multiplicative noise factor which can be estimated from the whole time series. I am stuck with the update of variance in presence of constrained additonal variance factors in em algorithm. But now it is clear why usual variance calculation is not helpful...thanks!

Comment: @GermanDemidov then it seems that your problem is *much* more complicated then your description says.